# AWS SDK Kotlin couldn't find credentials

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, macos, android-studio, kotlin

I am using AWS SDK for Kotlin in my Android project and my app always crashes with error

> aws.sdk.kotlin.runtime.auth.credentials.CredentialsProviderException: No credentials could be loaded from the chain: CredentialsProviderChain -> EnvironmentCredentialsProvider -> ProfileCredentialsProvider -> StsWebIdentityProvider -> EcsCredentialsProvider -> ImdsCredentialsProvider

I am using AWS secret manager and implementing the SDK in gradle as -

```
 implementation 'aws.sdk.kotlin:secretsmanager:0.17.5-beta'
```

My Kotlin code looks like -

```
   SecretsManagerClient { region = "ap-south-1" }.use { secretsClient ->
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            val secretValueRequest = GetSecretValueRequest {
                secretId = "prod"
            }
            val response = secretsClient.getSecretValue(secretValueRequest)
            val secret = response.secretString
            print("Secret: $secret")
        }
    }
```

I tried to setup the credential in my Mac computer as mentioned in this [article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-kotlin/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html), for both environment variable and also having a file named `credentials` .

Can anyone please help me to fix the issue

Answer (score 3):

Your problem here is the Android app will not read creds from the file system of your machine. To get around this, you can use the StaticCredentialsProvider shown in this example that is referenced from the Kotlin DEV Guide.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-kotlin/latest/developer-guide/cross_SnsPublishSubscription_kotlin_topic.html

Github URL

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/kotlin/usecases/subpub_app_android

Once you follow this -- you can successfully make AWS Service calls from the Android app.

[image]

**UPDATE**

After talking with the Kotlin team, you can setup your creds as environment variables then use this provider - which is mentioned in the docs here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-kotlin/latest/developer-guide/credential-providers.html

Code that works....

```
 SnsClient { credentialsProvider = EnvironmentCredentialsProvider(); region = "us-east-1"   }.use { snsClient ->
      val result = snsClient.subscribe(request)
      showToast(result.subscriptionArn.toString())
  }
```

This Kotlin Android example will be updated and published soon as well.

Comment: Okay thank you, but my point of using this AWS SecretManager SDK is to hide my secrets (API key) from others, but if i use StaticCredentialsProvider then it expose my AWS keys to other reverse engineers

Comment: We will work with the SDK team to update this use of the cred provider. When this was written (a while ago) - this was only provider that worked in a Native Android project.

Comment: Thank you very much for considering the use case of mine

Comment: Its a legit concern actually.

Comment: Please do kindly post a comment here, once if there's a update in the cred provider for this use case, so that I can be aware of the changes.

Comment: If for some reason, this is not updated, find my linked in profile and send me a message.

Comment: sure any estimate timeline as you have said 'if this is not updated' so that i can know by when if this is not updated

Comment: Looking into this now. Message sent to Kotlin SDK team to get best practice for creds now

Comment: Hi @smac2020 any update from your team regarding this